# import X3D/VRML

Tags: import

Using Blender 2.70a-r3 importing an X3D file does not really work as expected.
The groups are not imported and ElevationGrid is not imported, too.
Is there any way to get better import support with Blender?

Comment: if you have solved this by now maybe you can share the solution here ?